# UISwitch not changing value in Swift

Tags: swift, function, swift2, uiswitch

I'm using this little function in my Swift 2.2 app:

```
func changeSwitchValue() {


    if self.lampValue == 1 {
        self.switch0.setOn(true, animated: false)
        print("changed to 1")
    }
    if self.lampValue == 0 {

        self.switch0.setOn(false, animated: true)
        print("changed to 0")
    }
}
```

When the function is called, it prints everything out I asked, but the switch value never changes!

I tried using `switch0.setOn(true, animated:true)` in the ViewDidLoad and it worked there. When called by this function, it doesn't work . If I called this chunk of code by an IBAction, it doesn't work either..

Does anyone know something about this weird issue? Any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `lampValue`? You're trying to set the state of the switch depending on `lampValue` and we don't know what it is.

Comment: How do you exactly call this

Comment: @CharlesTruluck lampValue is the value of the light in my house. It can be 0 or 1

Comment: @ChristianDietrich this is called after a UDP package is received, but doesn't work either when I call it from ViewDidLoad or a button

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I tested again and it turns out that when I call it directly from ViewDidLoad, it does work. But when I call it from the UDP server function, it doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you call this stuff on the main thread you wrapping your code into a dispatch async on the main queue

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Indeed, I'm calling this from a `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` , when I move it to the main thread would that be fixed?

Comment: So, try printing the state of the button at the end of the function. What's it say?

Comment: no. just do the ui actions  on the main thread yes see my answer

Comment: @CharlesTruluck Actually, it controls a light. You can control the light with the UISwitch, but also with a mechanical switch. If the mechanical switch is triggered, the light goes on but the UISwitch says it's off. To fix this, the light sends a UDP command to the app saying it is on. Then the UISwitch should switch to the "on" state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure you do the ui actions back on the main thread

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) { () -> Void in
        // do the networking here
        // if you are done update the ui on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
            ) { () -> Void in
                self.mySwitch.setOn(!self.mySwitch.on, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out! Because the UDP server is constantly running, it was on the background thread. This function was called by the background thread which caused it. I should've known this! Thank you very much again!

Answer (score -2):

You have not posted enough code, but I will assume that switch0 is a UISwitch which is in a nib, and is declared in a view controller like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var switch0: UISwitch!
```

If that is not the case, all bets are off :) So my feedback is, are you sure switch0 is wired to the correct outlet in the nib?

Comment: Yes, it is. I This issue was caused by not being done on the main thread. Thanks for the reminder though :)